# Good test set accuracy (80%) but bad confusion matrix and low accuracy (50%) in classification report. What's wrong?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Built a CNN model for classification of cats and dogs images.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/drive/MyDrive/ML Tutorial/CNN/dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
print(training_set)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(                                            
        '/content/drive/MyDrive/ML Tutorial/CNN/dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(64, 64, 3)))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid'))
cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
cnn.fit(x=training_set, validation_data=test_set, epochs=20)
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('/content/drive/MyDrive/ML Tutorial/CNN/dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', target_size=(64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = cnn.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
print(result[0][0])
if result[0][0] >= 0.5:
  prediction = 'dog'
else:
  prediction = 'cat'
print(prediction)
result = (cnn.predict(test_set)>0.5)
print(result)
true_classes = test_set.classes
class_labels = list(test_set.class_indices.keys()) 
print(true_classes)
print(np.concatenate((result, true_classes.reshape(-1, 1)), 1))
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(true_classes, result)
print(cm)
report = metrics.classification_report(true_classes, result, target_names=class_labels)
print(report)
```

After 20 epochs I get 80% accuracy in test set.

```
Epoch 20/20
250/250 [==============================] - 86s 342ms/step - loss: 0.2846 - accuracy: 0.8801 - val_loss: 0.4681 - val_accuracy: 0.8035
```

But the confusion matrix and classification report looks like this:

```
[[170 830]
 [143 857]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

        cats       0.54      0.17      0.26      1000
        dogs       0.51      0.86      0.64      1000

    accuracy                           0.51      2000
   macro avg       0.53      0.51      0.45      2000
weighted avg       0.53      0.51      0.45      2000
```

Here is my [code link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fleZnJp9v2nmbyRTCqJN1RKadk5LXvi1/view?usp=sharing) and [dataset folder link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1fp3oqw0NhcbS0ZsbyUgVvtwiHUcJf1xo?usp=sharing). I believe there is something wrong in single prediction code. Please check.

Comment: Please provide a human-readable code link.

Comment: @Rahul open the link in PC. It will be human readable.

Comment: Code has to be in the question as text, not as a link.

Comment: generator.classes is not the proper way to obtain the true labels in a generator, this is a common misconception, you need to iterate over batches in the generator instead, which will give you per batch inputs and labels.

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely shuffling your test set (and labels), which happens by default when you create datasets using datagen. This is evidenced by having good prediction results (which does not use labels) but when evaluating with supposed labels, you get close to random prediction results.

In your test set (assuming you're passing the predictions along with this set when forming your confusion matrix), you need to create the dataset with the parameter `shuffle=False`, otherwise, you're passing a sorted array of labels with an unsorted (shuffled) array of test images. You're also using the same shuffled test set when you make your classification report, hence the perceived poor performance. But if you disable shuffling on the test set, you'll see your model will perform as you expect.

```
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(                                            
        '/content/drive/MyDrive/ML Tutorial/CNN/dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary',
        shuffle=False)
```

If you want a way to see how your model performs on the test set *with* labels, use the `evaluate()` method. You may have results similar to `predict()`.

```
loss, acc = cnn.evaluate(x, y)
```

Comment: No improvement. My model can't even predict this [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g6zrri1lYljnCnfyyWzRQ_AkmOJ0Tl5i/view?usp=sharing) @Djinn. I am completely fed up with this tensorflow library. If this is the result I get.

Comment: Did you rescale that image before predicting? Your model is defined by rescaling input images by `1./255`. Unless you have memory/time constraints, you don't have to rescale at all. When you say no improvement, is there also no improvement from the confusion matrix? Or just when classifying that new image?